# WSO2ESB 4.9.0 - OUT_ONLY not working for JMS endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

As per the documentation [ESB as a JMS Producer](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/ESB+as+a+JMS+Producer) setting OUT_ONLY should make the send mediator async. But instead I get timeout error as its waiting on response. What I found from various blogs is adding FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED would make it async. But in this case the proxy will respond at the send mediator. I do not want that, I want it to go to out sequence where I can generate a proper response message. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use clone mediator :

in the 1st target, define OUT_ONLY property and use send mediator to send your message to a JMS queue

in the 2nd target, create a response message and use respond mediator

Comment: Thanks, this does work. But is this the right way? certainly does not look like from the documentation.

Comment: OUT_ONLY is used to avoid a receiving callback to be instanciated (because there will be no response). If you set OUT_ONLY before sending something in the inSequence, you know that the outSequence will never be executed => you have to generate an appropriate response inside the inSequence. I've had a look to the sample and as far as I know how the ESB work, I think this sample is wrong.